# Unable to load default text in wordpress theme customizer API

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress theme customizer API and here is a section that I'v created:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('text_settings', array(
            'type'              => 'theme_mod',
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
            'default'           => 'some text',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage'          
        )
    );
```

When I visit Customize section in admin area, the text "some text" is shown. but when I delete that and place something else in the text field and save the changes, now that text is shown. NOW if I delete that text and save changes, the default text is not showing anymore. Why the default text is not showing anymore? and how can I make that default value to be shown again? Thanks.

Comment: Just specify the default when you fetch the value too i.e. `get_theme_mod('text_settings', 'some text');`

Comment: I did that before. My problem is not in the front end. The default value isw not shown in the customizer admin area.

Comment: That's because there is a value in the database (a blank string) which is being stored as the actual value, you could always check this manually and delete it if it's empty.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that? Should I use the get_option() function or something else?